# Reverse the String with delimiters also in JAVA

Tags: java

The input string is 
String sentence = "comp!ex, ex.amp!e";

Output should be 
String output = "pmoc!xe, xe.pma!e";

Tried this:

```
static void reverseEachWordOfString(String inputString)
{
            String[] words = inputString.split("[\\s,!.]");

            String reverseString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
            {
                String word = words[i];

                String reverseWord = "";

                for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
                {
                    reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
                }

                reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord + " ";
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the Output you get? Have you tried to use a Debugger to find out what the Problem is?

Comment: Part of the problem with your approach is that you discard your delimiters. It's easier if you don't use `String.split`.

Comment: I believe you may use `String.split()` to split at word boundaries (that is, before and after every word) if you can find the right regular expression. If that is true, you just need to reverse the words and not reverse the substrings that are not words.

Answer (score 1):

Find below a snippet from which you could start. In the code are additional comments explaining what is done.

```
String sentence = "comp!ex, ex.amp!e";
String[] split = sentence.split("[\\s,!.]");
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());
for (String s : split) {
    // reset the length and reuse the tmp StringBuilder
    tmp.setLength(0);
    // append the part the the temporary StringBuilder
    tmp.append(s);
    // append the reversed part to the output StringBuilder
    out.append(tmp.reverse());
    // if the length of the input is longer then the output
    // we need to add the separator char from the input
    if (sentence.length() > out.length()) {
        out.append(sentence.charAt(out.length()));
    }
}
System.out.println("input   : " + sentence);
System.out.println("reversed: " + out);
```

output

```
input   : comp!ex, ex.amp!e
reversed: pmoc!xe, xe.pma!e
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example iterates over the input. It stops until the current character matches the regualr expression. The expression is explained in code. It can get extended by more special characters that should split the input. The subtring between

- input start and index of special character
- or last stop and current special character
- or last stop and end of input

will get reversed and is appended to the output string. Please edit your question and provide more information, if this does not meat the requirements.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String reversed = reverse("comp!ex, ex.amp!e");

    //
    // Just to test...
    //
    String expectedOutput = "pmoc!xe, xe.pma!e";

    if(expectedOutput.equals(reversed) == false)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(reversed);
    }
}

public static String reverse(String input)
{
    //
    // Regular expression to match characters that should split the string.
    // ! or . or , or 'a sequence of whitespace'
    //
    String specialCharExpression = "!|\\.|,| *";

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    int fragmentStart = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        String currentChar = input.charAt(i) + "";

        if(currentChar.matches(specialCharExpression)
           || i == input.length() - 1)
        {
            result
                .append(new StringBuilder(input.substring(fragmentStart, i))
                    .reverse().toString());
            result.append(currentChar);

            fragmentStart = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to reverse a String with special characters without splitting the string.

- Convert `String` to `char` array.
- Write a method which takes a `char[]` parameter and loops on the `char[]`.
- Write a method which check whether `char[index]` is an alphabet.
- Store the starting index and ending index when `char[index]` is not alphabet and swap the elements in `char[]` with start index and
  end index.

Here is the working [code](http://ideone.com/xKfBIT) :

```
public static boolean isAlphabet(char x) {
        return ((x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') || (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z'));
    }

public static void reverse(char ch[]) {
    int l = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    while (l < ch.length - 1) {
        if (isAlphabet(ch[l])) {
            l++;
        } else {
            endIndex = l - 1;
            while (startIndex < endIndex){
                char temp = ch[startIndex];
                ch[startIndex] = ch[endIndex];
                ch[endIndex] = temp;
                endIndex--;
                startIndex++;
            }
            l++;
            startIndex = l;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String inputString = "comp!ex, ex.amp!e";
        char[] ch = inputString.toCharArray();
        reverse(ch);
        String reverseString = new String(ch);
        System.out.println(reverseString);
    }
```

Input : `comp!ex, ex.amp!e`                                                       Output : `pmoc!xe, xe.pma!e`

By splitting `String` with `whitespace`, you can use same `isAlphabet` and `reverse` method.

[Code](http://ideone.com/KV43EX) :

```
String inputString = "comp!ex, ex.amp!e";
String[] splitArray = inputString.split("\\s");
char[] ch1 = splitArray[0].toCharArray();
reverse(ch1);
char[] ch2 = splitArray[1].toCharArray();
reverse(ch2);
StringBuilder reverseString = new StringBuilder();
reverseString.append(ch1);
reverseString.append(" ");
reverseString.append(ch2);
System.out.println(reverseString.toString());
```

Output :

```
Input : comp!ex, ex.amp!e
Output: pmoc!ex, xe.pma!e
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that makes use of stack

Also there is a method `isDelimiter()` which allows you to add any number of delimiters.

```
static String reverseEachWordOfString(String inputString) {

    StringBuffer reversedString = new StringBuffer();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++){
                                                 // Get each character
        char character = inputString.charAt(i);
        if(isDelimiter(character)) {             // If character is delimiter
            popInto(stack, reversedString);      // Then pop stack into output string
            reversedString.append(character);    // And append the delimiter
        } else
            stack.push(character);               // Else push character onto the stack
    }
    popInto(stack, reversedString);              // In the end pop stack into output string

    return reversedString.toString();
}

private static void popInto(Stack<Character> stack, StringBuffer str) {
    while(!stack.empty()) {
        str.append(stack.pop());
    }
}

private static boolean isDelimiter(char character) {
    return character == ' ' || character == '.' || character == ',' || character == '!';
}
```